# Initializing LinkedList with generic parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to initialize LinkedList with class who has its own generic parameter but it would be an error on Unity 4.6. An example code is as follows:

```
public class Packet<T>
{
    public Packet(string args, T data)
    {}
}

public class Test
{
    public LinkedList<Packet> packets = new LinkedList<Packet> ();
}
```

and the output error is as follows:

```
Assets/Test.cs(13,27): error CS0305: Using the generic type `Packet<T>' requires `1' type argument(s)
```

Is it possible to initialize LinkedList with class who has its own generic parameter?

**Update:**

I would like to keep Packet generic after initializing LinkedList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to keep Packet generic after initializing LinkedList.

Not possible. Initialization is done at runtime and generics are already resolved to a specific type by then. Generics are only variable at compile time.

Comment: Just to clear up any misunderstanding: You can still do `LinkedList<Packet<?>>`.

Comment: @MichaelBorkowski - Not in .NET. You can do that in Java, but under the covers it is basically just an object underneath. But then, I am not sure if typing that literally is what you mean, so you've cleared up a misunderstanding with another misunderstanding.

Comment: Silly me, I thought I read a Java tag. Speaking in C# terms: You can still do `LinkedList<Packet<object>>`. I thought maybe OP meant to keep the inner `Packet<T>` type "generic" in means of being able to accept *any* type.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, you simply have to pass a generic argument to your `Packet<T>` class, as it is expecting a `T` object which is currently missing in your field declaration:

```
public LinkedList<Packet<string>> packets = new LinkedList<Packet<string>>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but i would like to initialize LinkedList by keeping Packet generic, is it possible?

Comment: It is possible if your `Test` class is generic too and accepts a `T` parameter.